# How can I burn the 12.04.2-desktop ISO-image under Windows XP?

Tags: iso, 12.04

Trying to burn this to DVD using the recommended Infra Recorder for Win XP, however the instructions (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) reflect "Select the Ubuntu CD image file you want to use, then click 'Open"

The "OK" button on the Infra Recorder remains grey

Did I correctly understand the Infra Recorder will convert a zip to an ISO ?

Many thanks

dbt

Comment: You should not have got a zip-File! Where did you download id from?

Comment: I think this would be classified as off-topic because it's Windows related. However, what zip file are you talking about? The 12.04.2 file that you download from the Ubuntu website is an iso file, not a zip file. It's okay if Windows is showing an icon of WinRar or WinZip, but the extension of the file should be `.iso`. If it isn't, download it again from the Ubuntu website.

Comment: @guntbert, okay, I just thought that the question would go into troubleshooting Windows, and deemed it off-topic. I haven't flagged the question though, wasn't too sure; thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure about the file format (if its a zip or a ISO file) please locate the file on your computer. Right click it and select Properties from the drop down menu. And make sure the "type of file" is an ISO File (ISO). If the file format differs from this you should download the .ISO file from the download page.

The link you provided should already give you the necessary instructions on how to use Infra Recorder

Comment: Not unsure about ISO just not provided in the zip file from primary download and alt sites .....?

Comment: Did you download your version of ubuntu from the following page?
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

If not download it from there

Comment: Yes still no ISO image in the zip file ......what am I missing here ???

Comment: @dbt It seems you got some software on your computer that automatically opens ISO files as an archive. Try installing software like PowerISO or daemon tools, and use these to burn the file. You could also try to burn the content of the ZIP/ISO file directly to a disk.

Comment: Finally got the "right" ISO (that allows try) & on a CDRW -v- DVD as my system doesn't recognize DVDs for some reason but still working on that one & all working as expected     many thanks to all for the assist !.......dbt

Answer (score 0):

No, when you select the image file it should be in iso format.
Open your zip file and check if the iso is there.

- If that's the case, extract the iso to a folder (you can drag and drop) and burn it using the same instructions.
- If not, download it from [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and use the same instructions from the link you posted.

Also make sure the field "Status" in InfraRecorder menu Actions --> Disc Information -->  says that the disk is blank.

Comment: No ISO file in the zip file from primary site and the same as provided or alternate site

Comment: No ISO file in the zip file from primary site and the same as provided or alternate site

Comment: That's an ISO file, follow the steps Kenneth told you and you'll see.  

Your system may show the icon of a ZIP file and open it with the same default application, but it's still an ISO file and won't interfere with the burning.

Comment: Ok so pointed the zip file at the Infra Recorder & the "OK" button still greyed out ??

Comment: Used CDRW & able to burn ISO & changed to BIOS to boot from CD/DVD first however only option is minimal install -v- try